# I want to import an external jar, but a warning appears during runtime. How should I modify it?

Tags: maven

1. pom.xml

   ```
       <dependency>
       <groupId>com.kingdee</groupId>
       <artifactId>k3cloudwebapi</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/k3cloudwebapi.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. 

[the location of the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMG7f.png)

3. warn message

[INFO] Scanning for projects. ..
[ WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for mes.xxx :xxx: jar:1. 5. 4. RELEASE
[ WARNING ]
dependencies. dependency. systemPath for com. kingdee: k3c loudwebapi: jar should not point at files within the pr
oject directory, $ {project. basedir}/ lib/ k3cloudwebapi. jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 259， column
25
[WARNING]
WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]

Comment: The system scope dependency triggers a warning because system scope dependencies are long time deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. The question is where is the jar which you are referencing coming from? Another Maven build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways to solve this issue:

1. Install the 3rd party jar to your local repository and reference it just like any other dependency. Refer https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html
2. Adding your project `libs` folder as a repository, as below:

```xml
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>localrepository</id>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

3. You can replace `${project.basedir}` with `${pom.basedir}`

You can try out any, but 2nd and 3rd way solved my problem earlier.

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve our problem

Comment: You Welcome :) :)